# Regex replace between 2 words and modify result

Tags: regex

I have this string example:

```
var s = 'type=audio&hls=&mp3=foo';
```

I would like to find everything between = and & and replace with quotes + matched value so I get this:

```
type="audio" hls="" mp3="foo"
```

(match is in quotes even if its empty and & gets replaced with space)

This is my regex but its not working:

```
s = s.replace(/=.+?\\&/g,function(a,inside){
        return '="'+inside+'" ';
})
```

Comment: Do you mean `s=s.replace(/=([^&]*)&?/g, '="$1" ').trim()`? Or just `s=s.replace(/=([^&]*)/g, '="$1"')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider your regex one token at a time, here's what it means:

```
=    matches a literal equal sign
.+?  matches an optional string that has at least one character in it
\\   matches a literal backslash
&    matches a literal ampersand
```

Among other problems, this requires that a literal backslash to be in the input string, and requires the string to end with an ampersand.  Also `.+?` can be shortened to `.*`, but is still wrong because it might include ampersands and equal signs in the matched string.

Also, there is no need to replace with a function, as JavaScript can do what you are doing with just a string replacement.

A better regex might have these tokens:

```
=       matches a literal equal sign
[^&]*   matches a string (possibly empty) that does not contain ampersands
&?      matches an optional ampersand
```

As Wiktor pointed out above, this could all be combined together like this:

```
 s = s.replace(/=([^&]*)&?/g, '="$1" ').trim();
```

Here parentheses are used to mark the portion of the matched pattern that is being replaced, the `$1` is used to refer to the marked portion of the pattern in parentheses, and the `.trim()` removes the trailing space.

Comment: What if match contains or ends with &?

Comment: Notice that the `&?` is in the pattern, but outside the parentheses.  Since the whole matched pattern (including the ampersand) is replaced, the final result will not include any ampersands, as desired.  The portion of the pattern in the parentheses (which starts right after the equal sign and ends right before the ampersand) is the portion that is included inside the double quotes in the result.  So, I believe this does exactly what you were trying to do.